# Iterate over multiple shapefiles, changing year from "2014" to "2015" in file name

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing

I have about 50 shapefiles  I would like to change each of their file names which contains "2014" to "2015". I would like to use a python script but have not been able to figure out how to do it. I have tried using the sample [script](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/rename.htm) from Esri but to no avail. I've tried to use other examples I've found [Looping through list of shapefiles to rename them using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68295/looping-through-list-of-shapefiles-to-rename-them-using-arcpy) but unable to work it into my problem.

```
import os  
import arcpy  
arcpy.env.workspace =   
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(fc)  
if fc.contains("4"):  
  arcpy.Rename_management("5")
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run your code snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search for a substring in a string using `if (substring) in (string)`, and then use `string.replace()` to replace the value you find.

```
import arcpy, os  
arcpy.env.workspace = r"d:\Temp\SE\RenShapes"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp") 
for fc in fcs: 
    if "2014" in fc:
        x = fc.replace("2014", "2015")
        arcpy.Rename_management(fc, x)
```

This will replace `2014` with `2015` in any shapefile name that contains it.

Answer (score 5):

You could also avoid arcpy all together:

```
import os

os.chdir(r'C:\Set_to_your_directory')
substring = '2014'

files = os.listdir(os.curdir)
for file in files:
    if substring in file:
        file_new = file.replace("2014","2015")
        os.rename(file, file_new)
```

This will replace "2014" with "2015" for any file in a folder.  It is also possible to place filters for the relevant shapefile extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used this to update a folder with .MXDs